# Meteor: "Error deploying application: Your account is not authorized to deploy to Galaxy"

Tags: meteor, deployment

As Meteor is discontinuing its free hosting I'm migrating to Galaxy. I'm following their [migrate tutorial](http://go.meteor.com/rs/627-RVJ-941/images/Meteor.com%20Hosting%20Migration%20Guide.pdf) but get stuck in the penultimate step, "Deploy your app to Galaxy". I created a galaxy account (let's say my username is "appname") and cd'ed to my meteor app directory, and did this:

```
$ DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy appname.meteorapp.com --settings ./settings.json
```

With this result:

```
Error deploying application: Your account is not authorized to deploy to Galaxy.
```

Variations of the command with full or relative path, and with quotes around the strings made no difference.

I'm logged in in my web browser, and meteor's documentation (e.g. [How do I deploy an app to Galaxy?](https://galaxy.meteor.com/help/deploying-to-galaxy)) mention no specific requirements. Do I need to authorize myself somehow to deploy this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With some help from Dan Ahmadi of Meteor I solved this (thanks Dan!). Answering here for anyone that has the same problem.

It turns out I had confused a Galaxy subdomain with a Meteor Developer account. I didn't need to create a developer account for meteor, as I already had one (must've created it during free hosting deployment) and so I was still logged in to that one.

To solve it:

```
$ meteor whoami
oldusername
$ meteor logout
Logged out.
$ meteor login
Username: appname
Password: 

Logged in as appname. Thanks for being a Meteor developer!
$ DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy appname.meteorapp.com --settings ./settings.json
Deploying to appname.meteorapp.com.       
Now serving at http://appname.meteorapp.com
```

Comment: i logged in with my meteor username instead of the app name. i had already added my username to the team, so i'm sure that helped.

Comment: I logged in as meteor user. Now I get this error:Talking to Galaxy servers at https://galaxy.meteor.com
Error deploying application: Server error (please try again later)

Comment: you can also add the `--owner=username` option